# Microsoft Graph - Problema para validar que un usuario se ha añadido a un grupo

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph

Tengo una aplicacion en **Azure AD** que tiene **asignado un grupo**. Esta aplicación se usa para el **login** de una aplicación web.

Cuando se registra un nuevo usuario en la web, se le envia una **invitación al tenant de azure**; el usuario acepta la invitación, rellena todos los datos que se le solicita y, una vez listo, se redirige a la web para activar su cuenta.

La activación no es mas que añadir al usuario al grupo asignado a la app de Azure y despues lo redirijo al dashboard de la web.

Hasta aqui facil. El problema viene en este código:

```
graphserviceClient.Groups[groupAdmin.Id].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToGroup).Wait();
bool findAssignation = false;
while (!findAssignation)
{
    IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage assigneedGroups = graphserviceClient.Users[userToGroup.Id].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
    do
    {
        findAssignation = assigneedGroups.Where(ent => ent is Group).ToList().FirstOrDefault(ent => ((Group)ent).Id == groupAdmin.Id) != null;
    }
    while (!findAssignation && assigneedGroups.NextPageRequest != null && (assigneedGroups = assigneedGroups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result).Count() > 0);
}
```

La primera linea añade el usuario al grupo de azure. Una vez finaliza, ejecuto el resto para asegurarme que el usuario esta ya añadido al grupo y poder continuar y redirigir al usuario al dashboar.

Al hacer esto, como el dashboard requiere que el usuario este logado, valida contra la aplicación de azure (al aceptar la invitación, el navegador ya tiene las credenciales/token del usaurio) y lanza un error en azure diciendo que el usuario no puede acceder porque debe estar asignado a la aplicación, cosa que ya he validado en mi codigo anterior y esta asignado al grupo que esta asignado a la aplicación de azure.

> AADSTS50105: Your administrator has configured the aplication to block
> users unless they are specifically granted access to the application...

Si el usuario se queda en esa ventana y comienza a refrescar, hay un momento en el cual puede entrar, lo que me hace pensar que, a pesar de que por codigo yo he validado que el usuario este asignado al grupo, Azure hace algo en background que tarda algunos segundos, provocando este problema.

El caso es que viendo esto, no se como puedo controlar o que debo mirar para redirigir al usuario cuando realmente tenga acceso a la aplicación, y todo lo que haga Azure en background haya terminado.

¿Alguna idea?